# Для создание квитанций и бланк. Конструктор.

Tags: php, sql, crm

Нужна crm система. На которой можно рисовать бланк, типа квитанций.Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [RetailCRM](https://www.retailcrm.ru/?partner=RCI-6925) есть функционал "печатные формы" - это то что вам нужно.